# Why are Stack Overflow questions shown in two colours?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, design

I was just going through questions on Stack Overflow, and I noticed that there are questions in two colours. It can be seen in the following image:

[image]

Now I tried to guess the factors which could come up for this, but no help. Can anyone tell me please what these multi-colour question section depicts?

Comment: Favorites tag .

Comment: Its because you Favorited Android. All question tagged with Android are highlighted.

Comment: oh.. Now I got it. Thanks man. I did not think of that. :) ;)

Comment: This is a most useless feature of SO, because you already have the possibility to make feed out of only tags you like.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I strongly disagree. I find it useful to easily distinguish between the two types of questions, I don't work with feeds. So maybe it's not the most useful feature in the world but surely not useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As told by two persons in the comment, its because I have Favorited a Tag and all the questions with that tag are highlighted for me.. :) :)

Comment: Yup, thats right..

Answer (score 3):

Because of your favourite tag, Here in this case which is Android.