# Question was migrated 64 days after being posted

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration

I just noticed [this question here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198565/152859) that was migrated from Stack Overflow one hour ago but originally posted 64 days ago:

> [image]

Questions older than 60 days [can't be migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890/152859), even by diamond moderators.

I just checked on some old question, and in the close dialog there's no option to migrate indeed:

> [image]

I have also checked with questions 61 and 62 days old - no "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" option, so this part is working well.

This leads to the conclusion that when there are pending migration close votes (cast when the question was less than 60 days old) the "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" option still show up and such question can be migrated even after 60 days.

While it might be useful, it looks more like an overlook in the mechanism, so can this be fixed?

Comment: The post had 4 close votes (off-topic -> MSO) that were cast within the 60 day timeframe. Then an hour ago another close vote was cast (off-topic -> other). Guess the code only looks for the consensus votes without looking at the dates. Talk about an edge case!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed!

Now, also checking for the age of the post as part of eligibility for migration in this code path.

With you in the next build (rev 2013.9.27.1040).

Comment: Cheers, but don't you think it's better to also clear any pending migration close votes/flags when the question reach 60 days old?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - It isn't a bad idea. Will keep it in mind.